# DNS issue, resolv.conf doesn't reflect interfaces configurations

Tags: networking, static-ip, raspberry-pi-os, dns

I open this issue because I have a weird behavior on my Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb where I have installed [raspios_arm64-2020-08-24](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2020-08-24/)

After I did the installation, I made changes in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0`  like this :

```bsh
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1 1.1.1.1
```

I put **dns-nameservers** to `127.0.0.1` (because I have my own setup for dns-over-https and I want to have a second one I case I have an issue that's why I put `1.1.1.1`.

But in the **resolv.conf** file I can't see that. I have only the first value like that :

```bsh
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I don't understand why I don't have a second line with the second dns entry like this :

```bsh
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

I have also tested to use two line with dns-nameserver and it’s the same result.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help  ;)

I have open an issue on GitHub too : [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/149)

### UPDATE

If I check **resolvconf.conf** I have :

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/resolvconf.conf
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
#name_servers=127.0.0.1

# Mirror the Debian package defaults for the below resolvers
# so that resolvconf integrates seemlessly.
dnsmasq_resolv=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
pdnsd_conf=/etc/pdnsd.conf
unbound_conf=/var/cache/unbound/resolvconf_resolvers.conf
```

And if I check the dnsmasq file I have the second DNS entry here :

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

If I ran **resolvconf -l**:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo resolvconf -l
# resolv.conf from eth0.dhcp
# Generated by dhcpcd from eth0.dhcp
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

But I'm unable to ping google.fr :

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping google.fr
ping: google.fr: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is remove the file you created in `/etc/network/interfaces.d` - you rarely (if ever) need to touch anything in /etc/network folder ... if you read `/etc/network/interfaces` you'll see the following:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Instead, you'll want the following added to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.200/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: I have just tried what you said but I always have only 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/resolv.conf after I restarted my raspberry pi. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If I ran `sudo resolvconf -l` I can see this output :
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo resolvconf -l
# resolv.conf from eth0.dhcp
# Generated by dhcpcd from eth0.dhcp
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
`

Why I can't see the same in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I have update my post and I'm unable to ping google.fr

Comment: your output from `resolvconf -l` looks unusually short - by the way, I only have 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf as well - so, that's not wrong - maybe you've messed up something in dnsmasq configuration